# "be interacted with with X"?

Tags: grammar, verbs

To say that something can only be interacted with [with] something else, say a mouse, is this correct? I seem to trip over the fact that the verb is like "interacted with" and not just "interacted".

"It can only be interacted with with the mouse."

"It can only be interacted with the mouse."

They both seem wrong, but I guess the first one seems less wrong.

Comment: "It can only be interacted with by using the mouse."

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't saying that only a mouse can interact with it?